# React Native - Hide Login button from left menu bar after user has logged in successfully

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
const datas2 = [
  {
    name: "Register",
    route: "MemberSignUp",
    icon: regisIc,
  },
  {
    name: "Sign In",
    route: "MemberSignIn",
    icon: signIc,

  }
```

Inside renderList, I have a list in which I am rendering the array of the Left Menu items. What I want is to hide the Register and Login icon in Left Menu bar of the homepage after a user has signed in successfully in sign in page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkACY.jpg)

```
renderList(datas) {
    return (

      <List
        dataArray={datas}
            renderRow={data =>

              <ListItem
                button
                noBorder
                onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate(data.route)} >
                <Left>
                  <Image source = {
                    data.icon
                  }/>

                  <Text style={styles.text}>
                    {data.name}
                  </Text>

                </Left>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have many solution for your case.

You can filter your data if the user is loggedIn. You need to split your route list.

```js
const unLoggedUserRoutes = {
    name: "Register",
    route: "MemberSignUp",
    icon: regisIc,
  },
  {
    name: "Sign In",
    route: "MemberSignIn",
    icon: signIc,

  };
const routes = !isLoggedIn ? [...unLoggedUserRoutes,...otherRoutes] : otherRoutes;
```